# accessing nt!Kd_DEFAULT_MASK using dbh.exe

Tags: windows

I would like to set the value of the above variable to 0xFFFFFFFF using command line. I was exploring dbh.exe and believe it will atleast give some clues on where the symbol is. But when I try the following command, it gives "no symbol found":

```
dbh.exe name nt!Kd_DEFAULT_MASK
```

I may need to setup symbol path but is there a way other than this?

Comment: Your question is a bit confusing ... so you were exploring `dbh.exe` (fine) and you expect a symbol _explicitly contained in the module_ `nt` (because that's what the name says) to be found inside `dbh.exe` why exactly? Did you simply try [`.symfix`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/-symfix--set-symbol-store-path-) followed by [`.reload`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/-reload--reload-module-)? ... still my initial concern remains. Could you please clarify?

Comment: I want to retrieve the symbol address from module nt, not from dbh.exe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
C:\>dbh c:\Windows\System32\ntoskrnl.exe

ntoskrnl [1000000]: x nt!*kd*def*


ntoskrnl [1000000]: x *kd*def*

 index            address     name
     1            1423400 :   KdPrintDefaultCircularBuffer
     2            14dd5c0 :   Kd_DEFAULT_Mask

ntoskrnl [1000000]:
```

as can be seen above do not use module prefix

```
C:\>dbh c:\Windows\System32\ntoskrnl.exe

ntoskrnl [1000000]: n kd*def*m*

   name : Kd_DEFAULT_Mask
   addr :  14dd5c0
   size : 0
  flags : 0
   type : 0
modbase :  1000000
  value :        0
    reg : 0
  scope : SymTagPublicSymbol (a)
    tag : SymTagPublicSymbol (a)
  index : 1

ntoskrnl [1000000]:
```

my symbol path is set via _NT_SYMBOL_PATH environment variable
asking dbh to be verbose about symbol loads I get this display
check yours 
I can say it works properly as far as I remember

```
C:\>dbh -n c:\Windows\System32\ntoskrnl.exe
verbose mode on.
DBGHELP: No header for c:\Windows\System32\ntoskrnl.exe.  Searching for image on disk
DBGHELP: c:\Windows\System32\ntoskrnl.exe - OK
SYMSRV:  BYINDEX: 0x1
         f:\symbols*https://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols
         ntkrnlmp.pdb
         8CFB49428DC86A330CE257778E0C2F931
SYMSRV:  PATH: f:\symbols\ntkrnlmp.pdb\8CFB49428DC86A330CE257778E0C2F931\ntkrnlmp.pdb
SYMSRV:  RESULT: 0x00000000
DBGHELP: ntoskrnl - public symbols
        f:\symbols\ntkrnlmp.pdb\8CFB49428DC86A330CE257778E0C2F931\ntkrnlmp.pdb

ntoskrnl [1000000]: q

goodbye

C:\>set _NT
_NT_SYMBOL_PATH=srv*f:\symbols*https://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols
```

Comment: I am unable to list symbols with the above method. I have set sympath SRV*C:\ga\symbols_wind*http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols and tried the above command again and still see the message "no symbol found"

Comment: I edited in the symbol path details of my setup I can say it works properly for me as far as I can remember  I am not sure what your error can be

Comment: I had accepted the answer. Yes, with symbol path details, it works.